# Passing arguments in pipeline script Jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkinsfile at the root of my git project which runs my pipeline. I also have some functions written in a different groovy file(smp.gvy) to which  I need to pass the build parameters and access them inside the function in a shell script. I am passing my entire mvn line as one arg to the function but seems like it's null.

In Jenkinsfile I have

```
properties([
  parameters([
    string(name: 'sshusername', defaultValue: 'testuser'),
    string(name: 'sshpassword', defaultValue: 'p@ssw0rd!'),
    string(name: 'featuretags', defaultValue: '@Regression')

  ])
]) 

stage("Regression and Progression Test on ${bddEnv}") {
    commonToolsInfra.notifyBuildMap(
         message:'SMP CD pipeline: functional tests started. ', 
         buildStatus:'IN-PROGRESS', 
         slackChannel:slackChannel, sandboxMode:SANDBOX_MODE)

    node("${FUNCTIONAL_TEST_AGENT}") {
         unstash 'tnd-smp'+"${BUILD_TAG}"
         unstash 'TND-INFRA'+"${BUILD_TAG}"

         dir ('tnd-functional-tests'){
             unstash 'TND-FUNCTIONAL-TESTS'+"${BUILD_TAG}"
         }

         if("${SKIP_FUNCTIONAL}" == 'false')
             smpTools.runSMPFunctionalTests("-Dbrowser=chrome \
                 -Dweb-driver=chromedriverlinux.bin \
                 -Dssh.username=${sshusername} \
                 -Dssh.password=${sshpassword} \
                 -Denv=${bddEnv}  \
                 -Dcucumber.options='--tags ${featuretags}'", "Test Report")
            }// this function is in smp.gvy see below                 
    }
}
```

And in smp.gvy

```
def runSMPFunctionalTests (String arguments = "-Denv=Dev1",  String reportLabel) {

dir ('tnd-functional-tests') {
    withMaven(jdk: 'Java 8') {

        try {

            sh '''

            if [ ! "$(docker ps -q -f name=tnd-chrome)" ]; then
                if [ "$(docker ps -aq -f status=exited -f name=tnd-chrome)" ]; then
                    # cleanup
                    echo "Removing exited docker container..."
                    docker rm tnd-chrome
                fi
                    echo "Running the docker container again..."
                    docker run -d -e JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -e JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m \
                    -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null \
                    --name tnd-chrome csa-docker.apro.nbnco.net.au/tnd/tnd-chrome:v1

                    DO_SSH_TUNNEL="true"
            else
                echo "Running docker instance tnd-chrome found...Using it"
            fi
            sudo chmod a+rwx ./src/test/resources/webdriver/*

            echo "Args for maven ${arguments}" //this prints null for arguments
            mvn clean verify ${arguments}

            '''
        } catch(err) {
                if (currentBuild.result == 'UNSTABLE')
                    currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
                throw err
        } finally {
                publishHTML (target: [
                allowMissing: true,
                alwaysLinkToLastBuild: false,
                keepAll: true,
                reportDir: 'target/site/serenity',
                reportFiles: 'index.html',
                reportName: "${reportLabel} BUILD ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

Two issues here I'm getting null if I echo the arguments passed from my jenkinsfile to a second groovy file. Also I have an @ character in the password so is it necessary to escape it or replace it before calling git clone with it.

Thank you...

Comment: How do you load `smp.gvy`? Afaik you either have to use a shared library (`library` or `@library`) or load other groovy scripts using the `load` step. There seems to be a badly-documented `script` step as well. Howevere I never used that... How'd you do it?

Comment: Smp gvy is in the same folder as my jenkins file I just point to it with smpTools= load 'jenkins/libs/Smp.gvy'

Comment: In that case you should follow the answer yong provided. Make sure to use double quotes whenever you want to substitute a variable from within a string. Of course you might need to fix other issues, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace the `'''` to `"""` to make Groovy doing string substitution.

```
sh """
    if [ ! "\$(docker ps -q -f name=tnd-chrome)" ]; then
        if [ "\$(docker ps -aq -f status=exited -f name=tnd-chrome)" ]; then
            # cleanup
            echo "Removing exited docker container..."
            docker rm tnd-chrome
        fi
            echo "Running the docker container again..."
            docker run -d -e JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -e JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx1024m \
            -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm -e DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null \
            --name tnd-chrome csa-docker.apro.nbnco.net.au/tnd/tnd-chrome:v1

            DO_SSH_TUNNEL="true"
    else
        echo "Running docker instance tnd-chrome found...Using it"
    fi

    sudo chmod a+rwx ./src/test/resources/webdriver/*

    echo "Args for maven ${arguments}" //this prints null for arguments
    mvn clean verify ${arguments}

"""
```

And escpae the `$` of `"$(docker ps -q -f name=tnd-chrome)"` and `"$(docker ps -aq -f status=exited -f name=tnd-chrome)"` by prefix `\`

```
"\$(docker ps -q -f name=tnd-chrome)"
"\$(docker ps -aq -f status=exited -f name=tnd-chrome)"
```

More detail can read [Groovy String](http://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#all-strings)

If you can't 100% make sure the changes is correct, you can use this Groovy online  tool: https://groovy-playground.appspot.com/ to verify changes as expect.

[image]

The string at right side is the string after string substitution and will hand over to `sh` step function to be executed.

Comment: I tried that but get this:


hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script2.groovy: 82: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 82, column 10.
            sh """
            ^

1 error

 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector

Comment: Would this be the right way for this particular line? 
sh  ' docker exec tnd-chrome bash -c "sudo git clone https://"${sshUsername}":${sshPassword//@/%40}"@git.myco.net.au/dart/myRepo.git"'

Comment: Because you put above string in `'` which not support string substitution, thus the string keep same as you write/see  and pass into `sh` step.  You can verify it in the tool i mentioned in my answer.

Comment: The Groovy docs and the playground link helped me figure it out. Thx @yong
This worked for me finally: 
            `sh "docker exec tnd-chrome bash -c 'sudo git clone https://${sshUsername}:${sshPassword}@git.myorg.co/girepo/myProject.git'"`

Comment: While that one worked... I can't figure out this one:

`sh "sudo 'mvn -q -f tnd-test-automation/pom.xml --settings tnd-test-automation/maven-bdd-settings.xml -Dbrowser=chrome -Dweb-driver=chromedriverlinux.bin -Dlog-level=INFO -Dssh.username=${sshUsername} -Dssh.password=${sshPassword} -Dcucumber.options=\\'--tags @Regression\\' -B -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn clean verify'"`


I get an error unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''

Comment: I think it should be `sh "sudo mvn -q -f tnd-test-automation/pom.xml --settings tnd-test-automation/maven-bdd-settings.xml -Dbrowser=chrome -Dweb-driver=chromedriverlinux.bin -Dlog-level=INFO -Dssh.username=${sshUsername} -Dssh.password=${sshPassword} -Dcucumber.options=\"--tags @Regression\" -B -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn clean verify"`